# On Topic Clarification: Java security in a server environment

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I'm a regular SO user but rarely use programmers.

I'm aware that Java in the browser is a security nightmare but am looking for evidence that Java in a server environment is sufficiently secure to use for new projects. Specifically, any good explanations as to why the broken Java security model isn't an issue on servers.

On SO, that would be off-topic as it has no clear answer. Is it on topic on programmers? The  [What topics can I ask about here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page seems to indicate it is (at least it's not explicitly excluded) but I thought I'd check first.

Comment: You are likely looking for Security.SE and in particular [Security of JVM for Server](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/32822/30204) and [Understanding JVM zero day in relationship with other runtimes](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36472/30204)

Comment: @MichaelT Thanks, I wasn't aware of those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on your focus. If you are looking at specific vulnerabilities and real-world details, then World Engineer's answer is the way to go. From [Information Security help center](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> **IT Security Stack Exchange** is for Information Security professionals to discuss protecting **assets** from **threats** and
>   **vulnerabilities**.

If you want to approach it from a more abstract angle of why one security model is more or less secure, in a computer-sciencey way, then Programmers would be better. But if you do ask here, it really needs to be more conceptual while also answerable. From [our help center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> **Programmers Stack Exchange** is a Q&A site for professionals and students in software development and related fields who are interested
>   in getting expert answers on conceptual questions about software
>   development.

Specifically, discussing the merits of each architecture would fall under "software architecture and design" in my opinion, as long as the question is worded correctly. It would have to be about a program you are writing (conceptual questions about software development) and not why Sun/Oracle did something a certain way (ask Sun or Oracle instead).

Answer (score 2):

It's not off-topic per se but if your focus is security then we've got a site for that called "[Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/)" that may yield a more detailed answer regarding the security aspects of the technology.